# How to join DecisionTreeRegressor predict output to the original data

Tags: join, merge, concatenation, decision-tree, predict

I am developing a model that uses DecisionTreeRegressor.  I have built and fit the tree using training data, and predicted the results from more recent data to confirm the model's accuracy.

To build and fit the tree:
    X = np.matrix ( pre_x )
    y = np.matrix( pre_y )
    regr_b = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 4 )
    regr_b.fit(X, y)

To predict new data:
    X = np.matrix ( pre_test_x )
    trial_pred = regr_b.predict(X, check_input=True)

trial_pred is an array of the predicted values.  I need to join it back to pre_test_x so I can see how well the prediction matches what actually happened.

I have tried merges:

```
all_pred = pre_pre_test_x.merge(predictions, left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

and

```
all_pred = pd.merge (pre_pre_test_x, predictions, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True  )
```

and either get no results or a second copy of the columns appended to the bottom of the DataFrame with NaN in all the existing columns.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was simple.  Leave the predict output as an array, then run:
    w_pred = pre_pre_test_x.copy(deep=True)
    w_pred['pred_val']=trial_pred